# SQL select from expression

Tags: php, postgresql, zend-framework2

I had the postgresql query like this:

```
select s
from generate_series('2014-02-19 00:00', '2014-02-19 23:59:59', '5 minutes'::interval) as s;
```

How I can make a similar query, using ZF2 select object?

I tried this way, but it is not working in zf2:

```
$select = new Select();
        $select->columns(array('s'))
        $select->from(array('s' => new Expression($s)));
```

How I can make this work, using zf2? **It is important that expression need in FROM part.**

Comment: are you zend Db_table ?

Comment: Generate_Series is not a table, where the select object of the ZF2 expects that. That postgresql uses a select statement does not imply that you are calling a table. Functions in postgresql start likewise with a select statement. If I were you, I would use a prepared statement.